# Excel: get values from a row containing a certain value in a specific range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Picture of the sheet]

This is my worksheet. I would like to get the row in the range [A4:D20] that contains the value in A1.

the cells B1,C1,D1 contain the value from the row 8 that contains the value in A1.
I used the following formulas:

- `VLOOKUP(A1;A4:D20;2)` for cell B1
- `VLOOKUP(A1;A4:D20;3)` for cell C1
- `VLOOKUP(A1;A4:D20;4)` for cell D1

but it doesn't work properly.

Can you help me?

Comment: use the forth criterion, `FALSE` so `VLOOKUP(A1;A4:D20;2;FALSE)`

Comment: Or sort you table on the first column ascending.

Comment: Thank you so much! now it works.